# No matching Localization found for URL 'http://xxxxxxx.com/'. Sending HTTP 404 (Not Found) response

Tags: dxa, web8.5

We are using DXA 2.0 CTP. After changing `BaseURL` for Website in Topology Manager we are getting this error

> WARN  - No matching Localization found for URL 'http://xxxxxxx.com/'. Sending HTTP 404 (Not Found) response.
>       2017-12-19 16:54:30,402 [9] ERROR - Failed to execute query
>       Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ServiceQueryException: Failed to execute query ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException: {"error":{"code":"4000","message":"Not possible to marshall single entity stream JSON: "}}
>          at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()
>          at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
>          at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.InnerSynchExecute[TElement](Uri requestUri, String httpMethod, Nullable`1 singleResult, OperationParameter[] operationParameters)
>          at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.Execute[TElement](Uri requestUri)
>          at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass19_1`1.b__1()
>          at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Caching.CacheHandlers.DefaultMemCache.DefaultMemCacheHandler`1.SetOrGetExisting(String key, String region, Func`1 valueFactory, CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy)
>          at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.AbstractODataService.HandleHttpResponseCode(Exception e, Int32 statusCode)
>          at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.b__0()
>          at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.PerformRetry[T](Func`1 block, Int32 retryCount)
>          at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.Retry[T](Func`1 block, Int32 retryCount, Boolean locking)
>          at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.DynamicMappingsRetrieverImpl.GetPublicationMapping(String url)
>          at Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.DynamicMappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping(String url)
>          at Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver.ResolveLocalization(Uri url) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\CdApiLocalizationResolver.cs:line 66
>          at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_Localization() in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:line 25
>          at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:line 51

After changing the `BaseUrl` I have run this cmd on CMS server

```
Sync-TtmCdEnvironment -Id CdEnvironment3
```

and also republished all content but it did not solve the issue.

## EDITS

I have dropped Discovery database and created a new database and run these commands:

```
java -jar discovery-registration.jar update

Sync-TtmCdEnvironment -Id CdEnvironment3
```

But it did not work

When I switch back to old `BaseURL` it starts to work.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO and based on my own experience, changing certain values of the topology and synchronizing with "Sync-TtmCdEnvironment" is not totally succesfull.

I usually find more convenient to regenerate the full discovery database with:

- Ensure the topology configuration is ok
- Empty the tables of the discovery service (truncate or similar). Or create a new Data Store DB.
- Start the Discovery Service
- Run the `java -jar discovery-registration.jar update` to update the registered microservices
- Run the `Sync-TtmCdEnvironment -Id Cd...` to update the topology configuration to the database
- Restart all the applications connected to that Discovery, as the mappings may be cached

This takes no more than 10 minutes, and usually is a better option, than to struggle with the matching localization error.

Comment: i followed your steps but it did not work i m still facing same issue but when i switch back to old BaseURL it start work.

Comment: Is the same discovery database? or a new one. Have you changed the discovery database reference? Can you try a "Get-TtmWebsote" to see the values configured?

Comment: The issue get resolved when i restart the content service .i think the PublicationMapping get cached on server.

Comment: added this last step

Answer (score 0):

The issue get resolved when I restart the content service. I think the `PublicationMapping` gets cached on the server.

Comment: But after regenerating the discovery database...

Comment: Raul it is not required to regenerate discovery database after changing the BaseURL just run Sync-TtmCdEnvironment -Id Cd...   command on CMS server and restart content service that's it.