# Cannot load page from model service DXA 2.0 CTP 2 Java

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

We are setting up DXA 2.0 CTP 2 Java version. While loading first time Java website is throwing below error

```
INFO  c.s.d.t.m.ModelServiceClient - Got response with a status code 500
    15:32:16.672 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  c.s.d.t.m.ModelServiceClient - Internal server error requesting 'http://10.0.0.84:8999/ModelService/PageModel/{uriType}/{localizationId}/{pageUrl}?includes={pageInclusion}' with params '[tcm, 5, /, INCLUDE]'
    15:32:16.676 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR c.s.w.c.controller.PageController - An unexpected error occurred
    com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.ContentProviderException: Cannot load page from model service
        at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.modelservice.DefaultModelService._loadPage(DefaultModelService.java:62)
        at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.modelservice.DefaultModelService.loadPageModel(DefaultModelService.java:39)
        at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultContentProvider._loadPage(DefaultContentProvider.java:48)
        at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultContentProvider.getPageModel(AbstractDefaultContentProvider.java:82)
        at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.getPageModel(PageController.java:292)
        at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.handleGetPage(PageController.java:121)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Does this mean your previous question (https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18202/no-matching-localization-found-for-url-http-xxxxxxx-com-sending-http-404) is solved? In that case I suggest you either self answer or delete that, if not, then I'm not sure if it is beneficial to open two questions about a single problem (better merge them with sufficient information).

Comment: @BartKoopman we are facing this issue on different environment. Actually we are setting up both DOTNET and JAVA version of DXA website.This issue is coming up in java version

Comment: Have you published all content, including the Dynamic Component Presentations? You can ensure this by publishing the entire Publication and make sure you deselect "Republish Only (Do Not Publish New Content)"

Comment: Yes i did publish all content and I also  ensure by publishing entire publication but it did not resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

CD Link configuration was not correct for content service after changing it to default value issue get resolved

Comment: Please can you add some details about how you solved it? This is really not clear.

Comment: @DominicCronin there is cd_link_config.xml file inside config folder of content service i have changed it's default configuration because of that i was getting this error after reverting back it to default problem get resolved