# DXA 1.7 No matching Localization found for URL for Assets and Version.json (.Net)

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.7

I have followed the SDL documentation to setup DXA 1.7 with SDL Web 8.5. I am facing a couple of issues from IIS as well as from my local debugging (IIS Express). Before I go deep debug into DXA core, I would like to get some help if someone faced this issue already.

**IIS:**

- I am able to access the web pages and static assets are loaded properly (Default DXA 1.7) without any issues.
- When I hit "Version.json", it gives 404 error. However, "Version.json" is downloaded under the "BinaryData" folder.

**IIS Express (Local Debugging)**

- When I hit any page from my local visual studio, the page is loading. But I am getting WARN "No matching Localization found for URL" for all the assets under "system/V1.7/assets".
- When I hit "Version.json", it gives 404 error.

I am not able to see any errors in "site.log" as well as from content service log file. I see only warnings (No Matching Localization foud for URL) in the site log for all the assets.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: pls go through this link [https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18202/no-matching-localization-found-for-url-http-xxxxxxx-com-sending-http-404?rq=1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18202/no-matching-localization-found-for-url-http-xxxxxxx-com-sending-http-404?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for pointing the URL... Restarted the "Content" service that fixed to pull the assets in my local debug environment. However when i hit "version.json" it gives 404 error.  when i check the log file, i noticed that "INFO  - Item '/version.json/index' not found for Localization '605'" it looks like something is going wrong from the core. I will debug "core" solution and check.

Comment: Version.json is an “internal” configuration file and is not intended to be requested through HTTP. So, the fact that you get a 404 if you try to do so, is not an error in itself. You.mention “I am able to access the web pages and static assets are loading properly”; sounds to me like you have a properly operating system, then?